# Why and when CNNs are used with text embeddings?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language

I am working on a subtask of QA in NLP where the objective is to determine how well a question and its answer are correlated. I have generated both sentence embeddings(USE4) and word embeddings(BERT) for the questions and answers in the corpus and stacked them horizontally along with dot product between them
i.e input = USE_embedding+BERT_embedding+dotproduct(USE_embedding) and fed it as input to a feedforward neural network whose task is to give the probability of relevance between the question and answer, however, the NN doesn't seem to work well on the test set(please note that I have fine-tuned BERT). After searching the web, I came across publications that are applying the convolutional layer as the first layer of NN to the embeddings, this is the part that is inscrutable to my Neural-Network(myself); paraphrasing,why is convolution layer favoured to detect useful pattern among embeddings?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought it would be the same mechanism for pictures. In 1D convolution, each filter would be responsible for some particular pattern or semantic information.

Take for example the following character aware encoder:

[image]

Source: https://zhangruochi.com/Subword-Models/2019/12/19/

The final vector can be treated as the embedding for the word where each number comes from a filter with respect to a special pattern learned from the corpus.

Comment: Thanks, Mr.Zhang.

Comment: Also, I was wondering how the operation would work since the sentence embeddings are stacked along with the word embeddings, how would the CNN filters convolve?? In-addition when should I use them, on what occasions??

Comment: Welcome to Stats! It(the method depicted) can replace the embedding lookup method, and embedding is just one method of representing the inputs(discrete characters or one hots). Other methods include BOW and DF-IDF. Once we have transformed the inputs of characters into the embeddings we can do convolution over the sequence of embeddings using 1D convolution.